# Conditional repeated test in Protractor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, protractor

I have started to use Protractor for automated regression testing and am new to the idea of asynchronous execution, promises, etc. I recently encountered a test that I can't figure out how to implement

In one web page there is a table with links in one column. When a link is clicked a box pops up with information regarding a certain item. This does not open a new webpage/tab/window but simply reveals more webpage elements and a done button to get rid of the popup. The test I am trying to implement is to make sure at least one of the links will reveal a certain element in the popup that it is associated with. In pseudo code I am trying to do:

click link->check for element->if element appears then finished testing->if element does not appear then loop and click next link->if no more links to test then test fails

I have done research about how promises and loops do not interact well, and after research have tried to use function closure and maps to achieve what I am trying to do without success. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to implement this test?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide some code so I'll have to guess the structure, but promises and loops actually *do* mix up pretty well if you're using [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)!

```js
const sleepPromise = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

(async () => {
  for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
    await sleepPromise(1000);
    console.log('one second passed');
  }
})()
```

Inside [asynchronous functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), you can put `await` in front of promises so that they behave like synchronous functions. Under the hood, they are still promises, but it allows you to write clean loops using promises.